# Generating a unique ID for a filename

Tags: python, django

This function generates a unique id for my files, which will be stored in the database to reference them. It returns the id if unique, if not, it generates a new one. My separate file server can then use these ids to locate and retrieve a file.

I'm planning on storing thousands upon maybe millions of files uploaded by users in the future, so this needs to be robust and futureproof.

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from .models import Media

def generateUID():
    uid = get_random_string(length=16, allowed_chars=u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()

    result = '%s-%s-%s_%s' % (date.year, date.month, date.day, uid)
    print(result)

    try:
        obj = Media.objects.get(uid=result)
    except Media.DoesNotExist:
        return uid
    else:
        return generateUID()
```

The `Media` model is a parent which stores the uid. There is an image model that `Media` can relate to.

For example:

Media `uid = 'test'`:

- Image `name = 't200x200'`
- Image `name = 'original'`

When the files are created, they are stored like this:

Let's say the ID is, for example:

```
2016-9-14_cKYT96osstPB8z2F
```

and the filename for the file that we want to get is:

```
avatars_2016-9-14_cKYT96osstPB8z2F_t200x200.png
```

Then the file would be saved like this in my file server:

```
media/avatars/2016/9/14/c/K/Y/cKYT96osstPB8z2F/t200x200.png
```

This ensures that there will be no collisions, and the file system is split and doesn't have thousand of files in one folder, which will damage performance.

Is there any way I can make this perform better or be more reliable? Avoiding collisions and performance issues is a must.

Comment: Have you actually run this for the `else` case? Because there's no `return` statement that would ... return the result.

Comment: The `else` case just runs the function again until an id which does not already exist is generated. I've tested it. The exception is what returns the result, since there is no other way in django to test if an object exists without it throwing an exception. If it exists, run the function again, if not, then return the result.

Comment: I can see that. If the function is run again, how is its result returned to the original caller? Calling `generateUID()` doesn't magically return that result. Should be `return generateUID()` e.g.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean, thank you for that. fixed. :)

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: systems with both a database and files are a pain to backup, since you have to ensure that the two backups are consistent with each other. Consider [storing everything in the database as the authoritative system, and optionally also exporting the content to a filesystem for web-serving convenience](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25197716/1157100).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code review:**

Well, your code seems ok, it can be improved:

- You can replace the letters by `string.ascii_letters`
- You can remove `obj` since it is not used.
- You can format your date using the `format` method, i.e. ˋ"{0:%Y/%j}".format(date)`.  That way, you can have a directory by year and a subdirectory by day in the year.

**Analyze:**

Instead of creating an UID and then writing a file, I usually process in reverse order and use `tempfile.mkstemp`.

> [It] Creates a temporary file in the most secure manner possible…

That way, you avoid collisions. Then, I use the newly created file name as an ID.

You speak about performance: note that the more you have subdirectories, the more you have inodes. This can decrease performance when you want to access the files.

**To summarize:**

1. Create a directory for each day using the format `"{0:%Y/%j}".format(date)`
2. Create a temporary file in that directory
3. Use the relative path and the filename to construct your UID. For instance, replace "/" and dots by underscore.

---

**Generating UUID**

If, for any reason, you can't rely on the file system temporary files, and you must create an UID yourself, I suggest you to consider using UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier).

See the Python module **[uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html)** available for Python 2 and 3.

For instance, you can use `uudi.uuid1`:

> Generate a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time. If node is not given, getnode() is used to obtain the hardware address. If clock_seq is given, it is used as the sequence number; otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen.

Example:

```
>>> import uuid

>>> # make a UUID based on the host ID and current time
>>> uuid.uuid1()
UUID('a8098c1a-f86e-11da-bd1a-00112444be1e')
```

If you want folders, you only need to replace "-" by "/".

Comment: Well written. Want to address that the server responsible for the files is separate from Django. So therefore I'd prefer to create an UID first.

Comment: Ok, I add an example **Generating UUID**.

Comment: Wouldn't the uuid be a bit long for looking up a file? I never see uuids that long on other web apps. Usually it's a sequence of numbers and a sequence of letters.

Comment: Also, removing `obj = ` caused an infinite loop and stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I second the suggestion to use a standard [`UUID`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) if possible, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Your technique doesn't guarantee uniqueness, since I would expect that when you generate a UID, you also place a reservation on it (in a thread-safe way) so that it cannot be reissued.  In practice, you'll be fine, because the huge namespace (62<sup>16</sup>) should prevent any collision from occurring.

The technically superior date format to use is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

[image: This is THE correct way to write numeric dates: "2013-02-27"]

I would obtain it using [`datetime.date.today().isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) (or just `str(datetime.date.today())`).